# How can I sum the values from a regexextract on multiple rows

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I have 3 rows. All of them have a `(number)&(letter)` format. For example, Say `5&b` is present on 3 rows. My question is:

How do I do sum just the numbers? I have tried:

```
  =SUM(REGEXEXTRACT(B3:B, "(.)&."))
```

I am trying to add the first value of all the rows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(--REGEXEXTRACT(B3:B27, "(\d+)&\w+")))
```

- `\d+` stands for one or more digits. `\w+` will stand for one or more words.
- You must use `ARRAYFORMULA` to extract data from the whole array B3:B27.
- `--` will convert text to number

Comment: I just wanted to add that if you include an OR operator, the formula will still work if you have an empty (blank) cell in the range: `ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(B3:B27,"\+(\d+)|"))))`